# Why using dyadic decomposition

Tags: harmonic-analysis, littlewood-paley-theory

In the context of Paley-Littlewood theory,  based on **divide and conquer strategy**  in order to separate high frequencies from medium and low ones authors use the dyadic decomposition that is they take annulus of the form $\{ \xi \in \mathbb{R}^d | 2^k \leq |\xi| \leq 2^{k+1}\}$ where $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. My question is why $2^k$ and not $3^k$ for example; why those **dyadic models**, do they have a special meaning or additional advantages?

Comment: It is the same definitely.

Comment: Dyadic decomposition are useful in singular analysis there are used to kill singularities in some integrals. Very often they provide some sharps estimate for singular operators.

Comment: That's a nice question and it is unfortunate that it received little attention. Like @Huxiyu, I think that using 3 instead of 2 as base would ultimately lead to the same theory, it is only less intuitive because it is easier to cut an interval in 2 rather than cutting it in 3. However, I vaguely remember some applications in which the exponent 2 was truly important. They should be in [this book](https://bookstore.ams.org/cbms-83).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use any integer $L>1$. I think people in harmonic analysis just use $L=2$ because it's the simplest choice. Note however that what they do is multiscale analysis for say a fixed (deterministic) function. When one tries to do the same (renormalization group analysis) for a random function, which is the situation in quantum field theory or the theory of singular stochastic partial differential equations, then it can be advantageous to use an $L$ that is large enough for the estimates to work. See for instance the article
["Renormalization Group and Stochastic PDEs"](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00023-015-0408-y) by Antti Kupiainen and in particular the remark between equations (16) and (17). His $\lambda$ is my $L^{-1}$.